Why does Leibniz formula for determinants equate two expressions that are not equal to each other?
Let's look at a 3-by-3 matrix:
$\begin{aligned}\begin{vmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{vmatrix}&=aei+bfg+cdh-ceg-bdi-afh\\
&=a(ei-fh)-b(di-fg)+c(dh-eg)\end{aligned}$
How in the world are these equal?
Because when we rearrange the terms of the first expression and factor out $a$, $b$, and $c$, we get:
$a(ei-fh)+b(fg-di)+c(dh-eg)$
We don't have $-b(di-fg)$, we have $b(fg-di)$.
Could someone please explain to me what I am missing?
Thank you.

$-(di - fg) = fg - di$

Just so the question can be closed, here's my comment in answer form:

$-(di-fg) = fg-di$


I have to say, this is probably the most embarrassing question I've asked :) Thanks.
